# Iterating over unordered pairs of elements stored in a collection

Tags: c#, mathematical-optimization

In C#, I have got a collection of unique elements and I want to efficeiently execute some code for each unordered pair. For instance, if my container holds {a,b,c}, the unordered pairs are (a,b), (a,c) and (b,c). The problem arises in the scope of performing a 2-opt optimization, thus efficency is an issue.

- My current solution looks like:

  ```
  foreach(var a in container) 
  {
      foreach(var b in container)
      {
          if (a < b)
          {
               // execute code    
          }
      }
   }
  ```

  Obviously, this can be modified easily if the operator [] is available to get the i-th element (i.e. if the underlying data structure is a list.) But for all other containers, the solution is dependent on the existence of some comparison function and not very efficient.
- I've also tried a formulation based on a LINQ statement that generates each desired pair exactly once. However, as expected, this was much slower than the first approach. This applies to a solution using `ElementAt` too.

**Edit: here is the (improved) LINQ code that was used:**

```
var x = from a in container
        from b in container
        where a < b 
        select new KeyValuePair<int,int>(a,b);
```

Still, execution is slower by a factor of 3-5 compared to the other solutions.

- Here is the way I would do it in C++ (obtaining good efficiency):

  ```
  for(auto it1 = container.begin(); it1!=container.end(); ++it1) 
  {
      auto it2 = it1;
      for(++it2; it2!=container.end(); ++it2) 
      {
          // execute code    
      }
   }
  ```

  Unfortunatelly, to transform this into C#, it would be required to clone the (internally used) Enumerator, which is not supported by the language itself.

Has anyone a better idea / solution?

Comment: What does your Linq solution look like?  Maybe you're doing something inefficiently.

Comment: How expensive is your a < b comparison?  You'd be better off using the Select() variant that inludes an index then you can simply compare the int indexes instead of the values of a and b.

Comment: Why do you call ToList() on your LINQ statement?  If all you are doing is executing each element code against each element you could save allocating that List.

Comment: ToList() was just used in the Code that I wrote to compare the different solutions...

Comment: Is the repeated iteration the problem or is it the comparison method itself? The best solution would be to support an index operator.

Comment: Comparison is rather cheep. If it would be otherwise, I would add a cheap function like comparing an int id etc. It is not that I can't live with the solution I've got. But for n elements, I do not like to perform n^2 comparisons that should not be required in my opinion, even if they take only a few percent of the total time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to copy the elements into a list first and then do the algorithm with the indexer (`[i]`) operator? Since the algorithm has quadratic runtime anyways it may be negligible to have a linear copy operation in front of it. You would have to find out the actual runtime for small, middle and large containers yourself...

I think it may be worth a try, this may well be a lot faster than working with the comparison operator each time.

You could also check if the container is of type `IList<T>` and jump past the copy operation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just did a quick check. Considering the time spent on iterating (including the copy), copying to an array improved the performance approximately by 20%!

Comment: In the test code mentioned above, I generated a List<Tuple<T,T>> holding the desired pairs. Replacing Tuple by KeyValuePair showed that a lot of time was thus wasted. Overall I've now halved the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the order, you can do it like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var a in list)
{
    int j = 0;
    foreach (var b in list)
    {
        if (i <= j)
            break;

        // execute code    

        j++;
    }

    i++;
}
```

If you do care about the order, you can limit yourself to collections that implement `IList<T>`, which contains the `[]` operator. Or you could copy the collection into a `List<T>` first, and then work with that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A quick check of the performance your code resulted in an improvement of some 10%. However, copying was even faster...

Answer (score 0):

Enumerators in C# are not the same with C++ enumerators from your question. In C# you have neither `begin` nor `end` elements of container. You only have `Current` element and `Next()` method. It allows you to yield much more sequences, for example - you can enumerate through infinity sequence of random numbers, which obviously has not begin or end.

So - you can't do it in C# like in your C++ code using only `IEnumerable` classes. The best way to do it is to use `System.Collection.Generics.IList<T>` interface. Many of types (such as arrays) inherit this interface.

If you use `IEnumerable` then inside your type you (in most cases) iterate through some collection. If you do this - you can just implement `IList<T>` interface.

There is another solution - in C# lists and arrays of reference types contains only reference to object. So - you can copy your data to local list and operate with it. But it depends on your memory and performance requirements.

Comment: You have to start iterating the sequence somewhere, so it has to have a start.

Comment: @svick It's just an illusion of first element. If you will iterate the same object in other place (on at other time) - you'll get a different first element. So, I think it's not completely correct to name it as start of sequence which represented by the class. It is only start of concrete sequence which you obtain from class in some place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware of the difference of C++'s iterator and C# enumerator. But still I'm missing the features I used to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Put your items into a List or IList, and then you can access them using indices in a very similar pattern to your C++ code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < container.Count(); i++)
for (int j = i+1; j < container.Count(); j++)
{
    var item1 = container.Item[i];
    var item2 = container.Item[j];
}
```

I'd expect it to be more efficient to iterate an ordered collection using indices rather than the n^2 comparisons.  The efficiency of the comparison operator is important but you shouldn't need to compare at all.